# How to achieve async behavior with nested firebase's forEach?

Tags: javascript, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I have a collection of products, each containing at least one payment document.

```
- products
   - productA
      - paymentA
      - paymentB
   - productB
      - paymentA
      - paymentB
```

I want to expose a route in express to fetch all products nested with every payment document they have, so much like described above.

Problem is getting Firebase to play nice with async-await. I'm trying to use `Promise.all()` but I can't get it working in the nested situation:

```
let products = await db
      .collection(collections.products)
      .where("active", "==", true)
      .get()
      .then(async (snapshot) => {
        let prods = [];
        snapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
          let prices = await doc.ref
            .collection("prices")
            .get()
            .then(async (priceSnapshot) => {
              let promises = [];
              priceSnapshot.forEach(async (priceDoc) => {
                promises.push(priceDoc.data());
              });
              return Promise.all(promises);
            });
          functions.logger.log("prices", prices);
          prods.push({ data: doc, prices });
        });
        return Promise.all(prods);
      });
    functions.logger.log("products", products);
    res.status(BASIC_HTTP_STATUS_CODES.success).json({ products });
```

I can see in the logs that some prices get logged after the products, and the returning object is empty.

It works when I go one level deep, so if I only query the products.

How can I successfully force the program to wait until all the product documents finish attaching their corresponding payment documents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies with this line:

```
Promise.all(prods);
```

Here, `prods` is a `({ data: QueryDocumentSnapshot, prices: DocumentData[] })[]`, rather than an array of Promises. This leads to inconsistent results depending on what you feed `Promise.all()`.

Instead, you want `prods` to be a `Promise<{ data: QueryDocumentSnapshot, prices: DocumentData[] }>[]`.

When you are trying to parallelise your code like you have, I would argue against using `async`/`await` as it can lead to weird side effects and more often than not, is not even required.

```
let products = await db
  .collection(collections.products)
  .where("active", "==", true)
  .get()
  .then((activeProductsQSnap) => { // QSnap = QuerySnapshot
    // somewhere to store the promises
    const fetchProductAndPricesPromises = [];
    
    // for each product, fetch it's prices
    activeProductsQSnap.forEach((productDoc) => {
    
      // here, you want to fetch the prices, wait for the result,
      // and then bundle it with productDoc's data. We want to do
      // this all in one promise that we can add to the queue.
      
      const thisProductPromise = productDoc.ref
        .collection("prices")
        .get()
        .then((productPricesQSnap) => { 
          // all this code is linear, no need for async/await
          const prices = [];
          productPricesQSnap.forEach((priceDoc) => {
            prices.push(priceDoc.data());
          });
          
          functions.logger.log("prices for product #" + productDoc.id, prices);
          
          return { data: productDoc.data(), prices };
        });
      
      // add to queue
      fetchProductAndPricesPromises.push(thisProductPromise);
    });
    
    // wait for all promises
    return Promise.all(fetchProductAndPricesPromises);
  });

// if successful, products will have the type: ({ data: DocumentData, prices: DocumentData[] })[]
functions.logger.log("products", products);
res.status(BASIC_HTTP_STATUS_CODES.success).json({ products });
```

Here is that same code, rewritten to use the `async`/`await` syntax:

```
async function getPricesForProductDoc(productDoc) {
  const productPricesQSnap = await productDoc.ref
    .collection("prices")
    .get();
  
  const prices = [];
  productPricesQSnap.forEach((priceDoc) => {
    prices.push(priceDoc.data());
  });
  
  functions.logger.log("prices for product #" + productDoc.id, prices);
  
  return { data: productDoc.data(), prices };
}

/* ... */

const activeProductsQSnap = await db
  .collection(collections.products)
  .where("active", "==", true)
  .get();

const promises = [];

activeProductsQSnap.forEach(
  (productDoc) => promises.push(getPricesForProductDoc(productDoc))
);

const products = await Promise.all(promises);

functions.logger.log("products", products);
res.status(BASIC_HTTP_STATUS_CODES.success).json({ products });
```